# Check if CVE-2016-10229 is fixed in my XEN Debian Linux Server

Tags: debian, kernel, security, package-management, xen

I use Debian jessie on a Xen server and now I am concerned about the issue [CVE-2016-10229](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2016-10229):

> udp.c in the Linux kernel before 4.5 allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code via UDP traffic that triggers an unsafe second checksum calculation during execution of a recv system call with the MSG_PEEK flag.

I want to check if the issue is solved on my server and VMs

On the Dom0:

```
$ uname -a                                                                                                                     
Linux xen-eclabs 4.5.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.5.1-1 (2016-04-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux 

$ dpkg -l |grep linux-  
ii  linux-base                     3.5                                all          Linux image base package  
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-4-amd64     3.16.39-1+deb8u2                   amd64        Linux 3.16 for 64-bit PCs  
ii  linux-image-4.3.0-1-amd64      4.3.3-7                            amd64        Linux 4.3 for 64-bit PCs  
ii  linux-image-4.5.0-1-amd64      4.5.1-1                            amd64        Linux 4.5 for 64-bit PCs  
ii  linux-image-amd64              3.16+63                            amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)  
ii  xen-linux-system-4.3.0-1-amd64 4.3.3-7                            amd64        Xen system with Linux 4.3 on 64-bit PCs (meta-package)  
ii  xen-linux-system-4.5.0-1-amd64 4.5.1-1                            amd64        Xen system with Linux 4.5 on 64-bit PCs (meta-package)  
ii  xen-linux-system-amd64         4.5+72                             amd64        Xen system with Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

The site sais, it is fixed in the package called "linux", in jessie 3.16.39-1

But which is this package "linux"? I don't have that package installed simply called "linux"?

How do I understand this connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got installed two XEN linux-enable kernel versions, exactly 4.3.3-7 and 4.5.1-1, and the regular non-XEN production kernel 3.16.0-4, 4.3.3-7 and 4.5.1-1.

The regular kernel packages for amd64 (64-bit PCs) are `linux-image*-amd64`, the XEN enabled ones are `xen-linux-system*-amd64`.

The corresponding XEN packages per your listing are:

```
xen-linux-system-4.3.0-1-amd64, 4.3.3-7  
xen-linux-system-4.5.0-1-amd64, 4.5.1-1
```

It seems from the output of your `uname`, that the 4.5 version is active, which means you are not vulnerable.

Nonetheless, while the kernel logs say it was fixed by v4.5-rc1, if Debian logs say only 3.16.39-1 is vulnerable, it means the fixes were back ported to older versions source code, as they use to do.

Nonetheless, you can always deinstall the older kernel version with the command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge xen-linux-system-4.3.0-1-amd64
```

Comment: Ah ok ,. The note on the issue sais  it is Fixed by: https://git.kernel.org/linus/197c949e7798fbf28cfadc69d9ca0c2abbf93191 (v4.5-rc1)

Comment: You caught me mid-(re)writing this. Added your comment to the answer.

Comment: And Why is the package called just"linux"?

Comment: I tried to answer that, edited the answer. If it not what I wrote, I do not understand that question.

Comment: So the package name for linux-image*-amd64 is called just "linux"? How could i have known that? Is this a meta package?

Answer (score 0):

`uname -r` doesn't show the installed kernel version, but only the **"kernel release"**

with `uname -v` you see the installed **version**
(which is further on the right in the long string in `uname -a`)

## Update the kernels inside the XEN VMs

In the config files for the VMs `/etc/xen/*.cfg` you have to edit the `kernel` and `ramdisk` parameter to match the new kernel in the Dom0.

Then:

1.

One of them is installed with Pygrub:

```
uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 3.16.39-1+deb8u2 (2017-03-07)
```

so that one is secure already through the regular `apt-get upgrade`

2.

In the VMs without Pygrub, I had to shutdown the VM and copy the boot-files to the `/boot/` folder inside the vm:

```
xl shutdown vmtest
mount /dev/vg0/vmtest-disk /mnt/
cp /boot/*4.5* /mnt/boot/
xen create /etc/xen/vmtest.cfg
```

3.

some vms had no boot files inside `/boot/`, there I didn't do anything, just rebcreated the vm